# Slide element 100% up and all subsequent siblings by the same amount?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Consider this document:

```
<div id="container" class="no-panel">
  <div id="panel">
    <!-- Can be any DOM with arbitrary, variable height. 
         120px is hardcoded only for the demo. -->
    <div style="height: 120px">Some Contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="contents">
    <!-- Can be any DOM with arbitrary, variable height. 
         300px is hardcoded only for the demo. -->
    <div style="height: 300px">Some Contents</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both `#panel` and `#contents` are supposed to be as tall as their contents, and not more (in the example I forced their height using arbitrary child `div`'s - just  for the demo).

I want to apply a class to `#container` that will make `#panel` slide all the way up (so it becomes invisible behind the top border of the viewport). At the same time, `#contents` should slide up by the same amount `#panel` did. I like that to be animated too (in the demo I used `:hover` instead of the class).

How can I do that **without using JS**? It has to work in Chrome / Firefox, but I don't care about other browsers.

I tried setting `translateY(-100%)`, which works fine on `#panel`, but then `#contents` would move `100%` relative to its height, not to `#panel`'s height, which is way too much.

Absolute positioning wouldn't work as then I'd need to fix the height of `#panel` which I'm trying not to do (it's contents are supposed to vary).

[JSFiddle with an example on how I'd like it to work.](https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/2/) - but with hardcoded value which I don't want.

Comment: like this : https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/3/

Comment: @MinarMnr - No, as your Fiddle relies on the fact that both `#panel` and `#contents` have equal height - accidently, but they do. Which won't always be the case in my real world usecase. If I add another line of text, it breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/6/ will work as long as `#panel` and `#contents` are the only children of `#container`. Also the `#container` is a little messed up, I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: change % to px `#container:hover #panel {  transform: translateY(-120px);}` https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/7/

Comment: @kalsowerus What do you mean that `#container` is a little messed up? Seems fine to me.

Comment: For me in my fiddle it only has the height of `#panel`

Comment: @kalsowerus Hm, I was able to get it to work within my app, using your approach. If you post it as an answer, I'll happily upvote it (I need to check out other answers to see which one I'll approve).

Comment: @kalsowerus Agree with OP, I also like that approach, so post it

Comment: Yes, I was actually going to point kalsowerus's Fiddle to you @LGSon. Testing my app with it now and it seems to just work, without nesting.

Comment: Yeah... and the only down side _kalsowerus_ and _lee comstock_ solutions have, is if you have content that comes after in the document, then it will be overlapped by the `contents`

Comment: @kamituel posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is putting #contents inside #panel, and using position: absolute to position it at the bottom edge of the #panel div.

```
<div id="container" class="no-panel">
  <div id="panel">
    <div>text</div>
    <div id="contents">
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#panel:hover {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#panel {
  background: orange;
  transition: 0.25s;
  position: relative;
}

#contents {
  background: brown;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leecomstock/an440a8q/)

edit: @kalsowerus has a similar but probably little bit better approach posted in the comments, which doesn't require nesting the elements.

Comment: How about `height: 100vh` on the `#container` - what if my `#contents` is so tall it actually is taller than that?

Comment: I just put `height: 100vh` to make the `#container` bigger than the elements inside it so I could use `overflow: hidden` without hiding `#contents`. You can't set `#container` to `height: auto` and use `overflow: hidden` because `#contents` is absolute positioned. You could either set `#container` to some height that you know is higher than `#content`, or hide `#panel` when it slides up by having a div over the `#container` that covers it

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that when you move something using `transform`, the elements position/size in the document flow doesn't actually change, it is only the elements visual position that changes.

This technique is also AFAIK the only one, where you can move an element its own *unknown* height (or width), though since its siblings doesn't know if it moved, they won't move either.

You have 2 options here, (CSS based), where you either nest the `container` inside the `panel`, as [lee comstock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972987/2827823) suggest in their answer, or use the `max-height` trick, where you set it on the `panel` with a value higher than what you expect it ever can be.

*If you can nest them, that would most efficient solution, as it will be fully dynamic*

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#panel, #contents {
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in;   /*  changed from "all" to "max-height"  */
}
#panel {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  max-height: 200px;                     /*  added  */
  overflow: hidden;                      /*  added  */
}
#contents {
  background-color: crimson;
  width: 100%;
}
#container:hover #panel {
  max-height: 0;                         /*  changed property  */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="no-panel">
  <div id="panel">
    <div style="height: 120px">
      Some Panel Contents
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contents">
    <div style="height: 800px">
      Some Contents Contents
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I kinda like the `max-height` approach more. Of course, animating `max-height` isn't perfect. I'll test things out. Thanks.

Comment: @kamituel I like it too, though one need to elaborate with the transition so it looks good, down side, it is not fully dynamic. The alternative that _kalsowerus_ showed in this fiddle, where the height of the container is dropped I find quite clever, also being fully dynamic.

Comment: @kamituel And with _kalsowerus_, if you still need the container to be full height, you can simply add an extra wrapper

Answer (score 1):

From our conversation in the comments, I came up with a simple approach (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de5nmqwe/6/)). The CSS uses `translate` to hide the `#panel` and `absolute` positioning of the `#contents` for movement relative to its parent (the `#container`).

Unfortunately this approach to affect the height of the parent.

**Note** that this only works as long as `#panel` and `#contents` are the only children of `#container`.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#panel, #contents {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

#panel {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* Has to be sized to fit its contents, and not more. */
}

#contents {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: crimson;
  width: 100%;
}

#container:hover #panel {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#container:hover #contents {
     top: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="no-panel">
  <div id="panel">
    <!-- Can be any DOM with arbitrary, variable height. 
         120px is hardcoded only for the demo. -->
    <div style="height: auto">Some Contents<br/>Some more contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="contents">
    <!-- Can be any DOM with arbitrary, variable height. 
         300px is hardcoded only for the demo. -->
    <div style="height: auto">Some Contents</div>
  </div>
</div>
```